# Determine $Z(f)=\{z:f(z)=0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Let, $f(z)=\cos(iz^3)$. Determine $Z(f)=\{z:f(z)=0\}.$ Indicate with a picture where the solutions lie in $\mathbb C$.

$f(z)=0$ gives, $\cosh(z^3)=0\implies e^{2z^3}=-1=e^{(2k+1)\pi}\implies z^3=(2k+1)\frac{\pi}{2}$. From here how I find $z$ such that it can be figure out the set $Z(f)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$
z^3=(2k+1)\frac\pi2 \iff z=\sqrt[3]{(2k+1)\frac\pi2}.
$$
If $k=1,2,\ldots$, then
$$
z=z_k=\sqrt[3]{(2k-1)\frac\pi2} \in [0,\infty).
$$
If $k=-1,-2,-3,\ldots$, then $p=-k\in \mathbb{N}$, and 
$$
z^3=(2k+1)\frac\pi2=-(2p-1)\frac\pi2 \iff z=z_{p,m}:=e^{i(2m+1)\frac\pi3}\sqrt[3]{(2p-1)\frac\pi2}=e^{i(2m+1)\frac\pi3}z_k, \quad m=0,1,2.
$$
Since 
$$
e^{i(2m+1)\frac\pi3}=\begin{cases}
e^{i\frac\pi3} &\mbox{ if } m=0\\
-1 &\mbox{ if } m=1\\
e^{-i\frac\pi3} &\mbox{ if } m=2
\end{cases},
$$
it follows that
$$
Z(f)=\{\pm z_k, e^{\pm i\frac\pi3}z_k:\, k\in \mathbb{N}\}=A\cup (-A)\cup (e^{i\frac\pi3}A)\cup(e^{-i\frac\pi3}A),
$$ 
where $A=\{z_k:\, k\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset \{z\in \mathbb{C}:\, \Im z=0\}$, and $bA=\{ba: a \in A\}$ for $b\in \mathbb{C}$.